# can't change pointer fields in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is kind of my first time using struct, so I apologize if it's too basic...
I have a struct which keeps a pointer as a field:

```
struct List;
typedef struct List* ListRef;

struct List{
    void *data;
    ListRef next;
    ListRef last;
};
```

I try to create a new pointer to the struct, this is the function I wrote:

```
ListRef newList(void* headData){
    struct List *list= malloc(sizeof(struct List));
    if (list == NULL){
            return NULL;
    }

    list->data = headData; // I checked here and list-> !=NULL
    list->next = NULL;
    list->last = list;
    return list;
}
```

The problem is that after the function returns the ListRef, the field 'data' is NULL (I checked and inside the function it's not NULL). I also added a test field which is not a pointer, and this one remained the same after the function returned the ListRef. This made me believe it has something to do with me returning a pointer within a pointer, but I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. Also, the field 'last' is not NULL - maybe it's because 'data' is void? I really am kind of lost...

Comment: You need to post a short compilable example showing the problem, otherwise we have no idea what's going on.

Comment: How did you pass `headData` to `newList()`? in other words, how did you call the `newList()` function?

Comment: `list->last = list;` looks suspicious, though. That's why "the field `last` is not `NULL`", at least.

Comment: Note: Creating a type that is a pointer is _OK_.  I find `typedef struct List* ListRef` confusing though.  It makes `list->next = NULL` look like it should be `list.next = NULL`.  Consider `typedef struct List ListRef`

Comment: Consider @ace comments.  The problem appears to be elsewhere - maybe in the calling of `newList()`.

Comment: This code actually works

Comment: To avoid the obfuscation, I would eliminate the first two lines of your posted code and always use 'struct List'  and when the code needs a pointer use: 'struct List*' which is MUCH clearer.  also, using instances of types and type names where the only difference is capitalization leads to confusion.  suggest using 'myList' or similar in the instances of the struct List

Answer (score 1):

The field `data` should be NULL only if you pass `NULL` to the call of `newList()`.

You say

> (I checked and inside the function it's not NULL)

If you mean checking with a debugger before the execution of `list->data = headData;` line, it most probably will not be NULL, as it is not initialized yet.
After the execution of the line, it should be whatever address `headData` contains (which is the function argument).

For the last point, the field last could not be `NULL`. It points to the object itself (as if it mimics C++'s `this` pointer). As `last` is assigned after `if (list == NULL)`  check passes, it is certainly not equal to `NULL`. (As Paul Griffiths indicates in his comment.)